# C++ threads: shared memory not updated despite absence of race

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, benchmarking, stdthread

I'm experimenting with C++ standard threads. I wrote a small benchmark to test performance overhead and overall throughput.  The principle it to run in one or several threads a loop of 1 billion iterations, making small pause from time to time.

In a first version I used counters in shared memory (i.e. normal variables). I exepected the following output:

> ```
> Sequential      1e+009 loops    4703 ms 212630 loops/ms
> 2 thrds:t1      1e+009 loops    4734 ms 211238 loops/ms
> 2 thrds:t2      1e+009 loops    4734 ms 211238 loops/ms
> 2 thrds:tt      2e+009 loops    4734 ms 422476 loops/ms
> manythrd tn     1e+009 loops    7094 ms 140964 loops/ms
> ...  
> manythrd tt     6e+009 loops    7094 ms 845785 loops/ms
> ```

Unfortunately the display showed some counters as if they were uninitialised !

I could solve the issue by storing the end value of each counter in an `atomic<>` for later display.  However ***I do not understand why the version based on simple shared memory does not work properly***:  each thread uses its own counter, so there is no racing condition. Even the display thread accesses the counters only after the counting threads are finished. Using `volatile` did not help either.

Could anyone explain me this strange behaviour (as if memory was not updated) and tell me if I missed something ?

Here the shared variables:

```
const int maxthread = 6;
atomic<bool> other_finished = false;
atomic<long> acounter[maxthread];
```

Here the code of the threaded function:

```
void foo(long& count, int ic, long maxcount)   
{
    count = 0;  
    while (count < maxcount) {
        count++;
        if (count % 10000000 == 0)
            this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::microseconds(1));
    }
    other_finished = true;      // atomic: announce work is finished
    acounter[ic] = count;       // atomic: share result 
}
```

Here an example of how I call benchmark the threads:

```
mytimer.on();                 // second run, two threadeds
thread t1(foo, counter[0], 0, maxcount);  // additional thread
foo(counter[1], 1, maxcount);         // main thread
t1.join();                    // wait end of additional thread
perf = mytimer.off();     
display_perf("2 thrds:t1", counter[0], perf);  // non atomic version of code
display_perf("2 thrds:t2", counter[1], perf);
display_perf("2 thrds:tt", counter[0] + counter[1], perf);
```

Comment: Yes ! Sorry:  MSVC 2013 on Win 8.1, with an intel i7

Comment: Most likely not related to the problem. However, regarding performance, you should take a look at [False sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing), i.e. different threads shouldn't write to variables, that are on the same cache line, in your case `counter`.

Comment: Very interesting article on false sharing.  I suspected something with the cache.  However after your solution with std::ref(), I created a vriant of my programme using a global array and without reference passing.  This worked fine, which confirmed that the problem was not the cache but the reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simplified version to reproduce the problem:

```
void deep_thought(int& value) { value = 6 * 9; }

int main()
{
    int answer = 42;
    std::thread{deep_thought, answer).join();
    return answer; // 42
}
```

It looks like passing a reference to `answer` to the worker function, and assigning `6 * 9` to the reference and therefore to `answer`. However, the constructor of `std::thread` makes a copy of `answer` and passes a reference to the copy to the worker function, and the variable `answer` in the main thread is never changed.

Both GCC-4.9 and Clang-3.5 reject the above code, because the worker function can not be invoked with a lvalue reference. You can solve the problem by passing the variable with `std::ref`:

```
    std::thread{deep_thought, std::ref(answer)}.join();
```

Comment: Might want to mention that the solution is to use a `std::reference_wrapper`.